# How to get shape type in Visio using VBA?

Tags: vba, visio

I'm using Visio 2016 and VBA and am working with a Visio file with over 100 tabs. I need to extract the data (mainly text, connector from/to, and shape) for data processing for a processing engine.

I'm trying to figure out how to get the shape type name in Visio. For example, in a flowchart, I'm trying to figure out how to tell if a shape is a process, decision, data, etc.

Using the shape type property seems to always return 3 which appears to be visTypeShape from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.visshapetypes.

Anyone have any idea how to get the shape type with VBA? I'm also ok with parsing the XML from the OpenXML file directly but I can't find the shape name in the XML files either.

I appreciate any help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure why my question got downvoted but I just figured out the answer so I'm sharing in case someone else runs into this issue and I didn't find the answer anywhere else.

The shape.Master.Name will return the shape name, but you need to check if it's Nothing first in case it's not a shape. I didn't do that and it kept breaking the script.

This snippet will loop through all the shapes on the active page and get the ID and shape name:

```
Public Sub GetShapeAndID()

Dim visShape As Shape

For Each visShape In ActivePage.Shapes
    If Not visShape.Master Is Nothing Then
     Debug.Print visShape.ID & " - " & visShape.Master.Name
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Also bear in mind that Masters have local (Name) and universal (NameU) properties.  The local name is what you'll see in the UI and the universal name is one that can only be changed in code once it's initially set. See this for more details: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visio/2006/07/27/name-and-nameu/

Comment: That's great info to know. It made me double check my export, and thanksfully it appears they didn't override the names in the Visio documents I was provided so I am good for now. I'll keep that in mind for the future if I need to do this again. Thanks, @JohnGoldsmith!